# Add text below "Lost your password?" field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am kinda new with WooCommerce and WordPress overall.
So, I am trying to add some text below to "Lost your password" field at My Account WooCommerce login form, But I did not succeed even though I added `p` `anchor` below the forget my password section in the `login-form.php` file but in fact nothing changed on the page. What am I supposed to do?
Basically, what I want to do is add a text line with a link to another page. I'd like if someone could tell me in which file I should add my code lines and if it possible to do it.

[The picture shows what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhzYt.png)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "login_footer" hook to add text below "Lost your password" field.
You can find more hooks in wp-login.php in your wordpress root directory and add text based on your requirements.

Add Code like this somewhere in child theme functions.php:

```
add_action('login_footer', 'add_text_forgot_pass');
function add_text_forgot_pass(){
    echo "Extra TEXT";
}
```

Let us know if you have more questions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
But, what do you mean login_footer? i'm speaking about adding text in they woocommerce login page on the my account field.

Comment: I see your screenshot shared above.
You can use the "login_footer" hook to add text where you are pointing in the screen shot.
Simply paste code in functions.php and text will show up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below hook to add any thing after login form at WooCommerce My Account page. Add this code to your active theme's `function.php` file.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_customer_login_form', 'add_text_after_login');

function add_text_after_login() {
    echo "Custom Content";
}
```

`woocommerce_after_customer_login_form` & `woocommerce_before_customer_login_form` these two hooks are used to add content after or before login form.